# SWIFT coding error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

```
var filteredImage: UIImage?
var originalImage = UIImage(named: "scenery")
var imageProcessor: ImageProcessor!
var activeFilter: ImageProcessor.Filter!

@IBAction func applyFilter(sender: UIButton) {
    activeFilter = ImageProcessor.Filter(rawValue(sender.titleLabel?.text)!)

    print(activeFilter)

    filteredImage = imageProcessor.process(originalImage!, filter: activeFilter!, parameter: 0.5)
}
```

Here`s a part of the code, when I run it, it shows

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on "filteredImage = imageProcessor.process(originalImage!, filter: activeFilter!, parameter: 0.5)"

I thought some parameters must be nil so I check throughly but I failed.

Comment: How did you "check thoroughly"?

Comment: Are you calling `imageProcessor = ImageProcessor()` somewhere?

Comment: I checked every parameters for this sentence to make sure they are not nil, but the problem still exists.

Comment: and i didn't call imageProcessor = ImageProcessor() on other places.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "scenery" exists in your image.assets?

Comment: Yes, to make sure originalImage is not nil, i set it as a photo that exists in assets.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve already solve this question

the key is I forgot to define imageProcessor

so by adding "var imageProcessor: ImageProcessor!"

It`s done

thanks for you guys help anyway!